# ruby each_line comparison only returns last string

Tags: ruby

Code:

```
class Comparer

words = "asdf-asdf-e-e-a-dsf-bvc-onetwothreefourfive-bob-john"
foundWords = []

File.foreach('words.txt') do |line|
    substr = "#{line}"
    if words.include? substr
        puts "Found " + substr
        foundWords << substr            
    end
end

wordList = foundWords.join("\n").to_s               
puts "Words found: " + wordList

end
```

words.txt:

```
one
blah-blah-blah
123-5342-123123
onetwo
onetwothree
onetwothreefour
```

I'd like the code to return all instances of include?, however when the code is run, wordList only contains the last line of words.txt ("onetwothreefour".) Why don't the other lines in words.txt get factored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all other lines you expect to be found, they have "hidden" newline character at the end. You can see for yourself.

```
File.foreach('words.txt') do |line|
  puts line.inspect
  # or
  p line
end
```

You can get rid of newlines by using `chomp!` method on `line`.

```
File.foreach('words.txt') do |line|
  line.chomp!

  # proceed with your logic
end
```